# Using Enthought Canopy Python and Pyglet

Tags: windows, python-2.7, enthought, canopy, pyglet

Playing around with a little Pyglet, using Enthought Canopy.  Trying to run just the standard 'Hello World' like example and am getting an error.

Here is my code:

```
import pyglet

game_window = pyglet.window.Window()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyglet.app.run()
```

And here is the error:

> WindowsError                              Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>
> ----> 4 window = pyglet.window.Window(800,600)

It also comes back with an GLException pointing to the same line on occasion.

Answer (score 1):

The version of Pyglet that came packaged in Canopy was 1.1.4, I updated to 1.2.4, and now it works.